# How to select all names in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, cell, names, vba

I am working with a large Excel file, where I have defined around 2000 names for cells. In addition the excel contains formulas, these formulas are already entered with references to cells (`A23-B24`). I want to change the cells references by the defined names (instead of `A23-B24` having `VARIABLE_100-VARIABLE_120`).

I know this is possible by selecting "Apply names" and then select the defined names from the list. Because I have around 2000 defined names, I would like to select all the names at once from the menu, but I cannot find an option, so I have to select one by one. I have been looking if there was an option for enabling the multiple selection on the menu, but I have not found such an option. 
A work around for me would be to create a macro that applies to the selected range of formulas the selected names. Something like this:

```
Sub Macro1()

' Macro1 Macro

Selection.ApplyNames Names:=Array  ("ATL_BV_XP", "ATL_BV_XP..EUN", "ATL_PK_XP", _
    "ATL_PK_XP..EUN", "CHN_PK_IM", "CHN_PK_IM..EUN", "CHN_PK_IM..SHREUN", _
    "E15_AG_AH", "E15_AG_EPA", "E15_AG_SFP", "E15_AG_SFP..CF" _
    , "E15_APF_FE"), IgnoreRelativeAbsolute:=True, UseRowColumnNames:=True, _
    OmitColumn:=True, OmitRow:=True, Order:=1, AppendLast:=False
End Sub
```

My problem is that because I have a large number of defined names (already wrote like twice that around 2000), listing all names in the macro code becomes really complex. I thought that probably a workaround would be to create a list including all defined names within the code. Does someone has an idea how to do this? I have looking around and some codes suggest a loop while other say it is possible to extract a list. Nonetheless I have not been able to find a way to do it.

Comment: Did you look for the vba object model "names": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff196278%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer Christine Ross, I am not a vba expert, currently I am checking the following website https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841280.aspx
Probably using the last example I would be able : first to create a list of all the names, then apply that list to a selected range of formulas to replace the cell references by the corresponding names.

Comment: So can you please define your problem more clearly? While reading the question it seems that you want to insert names into formulas by using some dropdown, etc. But while reading the comments it seems that you already have names in formulas and you want to change them to actual references (e.g. in formula you have a name `name1` and you want to replace that with `Sheet1!A1`)?

Comment: Even when done manually ("Formulas" > "Apply Names") I cannot make it change my dummy formulas. I suspect a bug which is [open for over 10 years...](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=29635)

Comment: Thanks for the follow up and the reply. Actually even after managing to select the names manually by clicking one by one, Excel crashes very often. The solution for me was to create a dictionary in a CSV file by exporting the formulas as text as well as references, then in R I apply a replacement in three lines of code. My option would have been to stay in Excel, but certainly some processes are easier using alternatives. Nonetheless I will keep trying further this option, most likely there should be a solution. Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation at msdn.microsoft.com says

> Names: An array of the names to be applied. *If this argument is omitted, all names on the sheet are applied to the range*.

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196578(v=office.15).aspx

Following on that try this:

```
Selection.ApplyNames _
    IgnoreRelativeAbsolute:=True, UseRowColumnNames:=True, _
    OmitColumn:=True, OmitRow:=True, Order:=1, AppendLast:=False
```

This should work depending on the `Scope` of the `Defined Names` and their visibility. Try that and let us know the results.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried the piece of code below, it did not work. Excel prompts an error message indicating that no references where found. I tried instead to use 

Cells.ApplyNames _
    IgnoreRelativeAbsolute:=True, UseRowColumnNames:=True, _
    OmitColumn:=True, OmitRow:=True, Order:=1, AppendLast:=False
The error message is the same, thus I think that by not entering a value for "Names" it is not using the defined names on the workbook or the worksheet. My other option was to create an array and then use this array as a value for names.Nonetheless it did not work.

Comment: Well, that is what Microsoft claims, I was expecting it to worked at least for the Defined Names with same Scope and for the ones at Workbook level, so all others can be taken care via a separated procedure. Your goal of replacing all the “A1” references in your workbook’s formulas with the corresponding “Defined Names” makes all the sense to me, as a matter of fact I believe that’s the entire purpose of the Defined Names. Would it be possible for you to place your file somewhere in the internet so I can have a detailed view of the “Scope” and magnitude of the Defined Names involved. Cheers…

Answer (score 0):

It may already be available to you.  Say we have defined the Names *Cost*, *Profit*, *Tax*

When typing a formula, have the *Formula Tab* open and you can always pull-down those names:

[image]

A macro would be nice, but I don't know how to invoke a macro in the middle of editing.

Comment: Thanks for the input, the problem is that my file has more than 2000 names and it is already entered as references to cells, so ideally I would like to replace those references by the names in one single step.

Comment: @user3279722  A starting point would be to pick some cell and run `ActiveCell.ListNames` to generate a table of names and references.  You could then write some kind of find/replace macro to loop over the formulas and make changes.

Comment: Never knew about `.ListNames`! That would have saved me lots of some time during my last project :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I know that .ListNames, creates a list of the defines names and the ranges they cover. I think it should be possible to create an array from this list and enter this as the value for "names" in the ApplyNames function. The following piece of code is made with that intention, but it does not work

Sub Macro1()

' Macro1 Macro

Dim Arr() As Variant
Arr = Range("A5:A2100")
Selection.ApplyNames _
Names:=Arr, IgnoreRelativeAbsolute:=True, UseRowColumnNames:=True, _
OmitColumn:=True, OmitRow:=True, Order:=1, AppendLast:=False

End Sub

The problem seems to be the "Range" option.